# Which one is grammatically correct? past/met or present/meet

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, phrasal-verbs, present-tense

- I'd like to thank you for taking the time **to meet** me last day.

or

- I'd like to thank you for taking the time **to met** me last day?

Comment: ... to meet me yesterday.

Comment: By the way, the normal adverb is _grammatically_. "Grammarly" exists as the name of a tool and website, but it is not in general use as an English word.

Comment: "Meet"  in "to meet"  isn't present tense.  It's an infinitive and is untensed.  There is no past infinitive.  (There is a periphrastic perfect infinitive, "(to) have met", consisting of the infinitive "have"  followed by the past participle "met".)

Answer (score 1):

The infinitive particle is always followed by the base form of the verb, so *to meet*, never *to met*.

*To met* cannot occur in a sentence (unless if the two words are in different constituents and happen to come together, e.g. *The lawyer I sent the emails to met up with us last week*: *The lawyer [I sent the emails to] met up with us last week*).

If the infinitive is passive, past, or continuous, the *to* is followed by the base form of an auxiliary, *be* or *have*; in that case, the main verb will be in the form of an appropriate participle: *to be meeting*, *to have met*, *to have been meeting*, *to be met*, *to have been met* (the last two are passive).

Answer (score 0):

[**This page explains,**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked)

> We form the perfect infinitive with *to have* + the -*ed* form of a verb.

As,

> She claims **to have met** a number of famous people, but I don’t believe her.

> I would prefer **to have stayed** at a small, family-run hotel than a big international chain.

etc.

For you information, there is no "to had..." "to has...".

Comment: I think it is better to write, __to have + **past participle** of the verb_. Also I feel there is no need to mention the first sentence.

Comment: Would you use "to have met"  in the OP's sentence? ("I'd like to thank you for taking the time to meet me").  I wouldn't - I think it reads much better with "to meet".  But the OP could say "I'm glad to have met you".

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh "The -ed form of the verb" is a direct quote from the website Kentaro is referring to.  Although "past participle" is the traditional and most widely used term, some people prefer to call it the "-ed form" or "-ed participle" because the term "past" is misleading (participles have no tense, and the past participle is used in passives, including in constructions that have nothing to do with the past, like "it is being published").